# Content must fill available space down to footer and highchart must be reponsive (no scrolling allowed)

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, flexbox

[My Actual App (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFEks.png)

https://jsfiddle.net/o4wbu3y6/54/ (simplified, but same concept) (same code as right here)

```js
Highcharts.chart('chart-goes-here', {
    chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Fruit Consumption'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Fruit eaten'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [1, 0, 4]
  }, {
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 7, 3]
  }]
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  /* display: flex; */
  /* flex-flow: column; */
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.box .row.content {
  /* flex: 1 1 auto; */
  height: 100%; /* If I disable this, the highchart will just shrink back to it's undefined/default height */
  width: 100%;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: skyblue;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

.box .row.footer {
  /* flex: 0 0 200px; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  <div class="row content" id="chart-goes-here"></div>
  <div class="row footer">
    <p></p>If the footer grows, the content must shrink
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p></p>If the footer grows, the content must shrink
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm creating a chart using highcharts, and making my own custom built table underneath (div.row.footer). I want the table/footer at a later point to be interactive for the end user (hence why I want it to be in the footer). Since the footer is going to be interactive, it must *always* be shown. The footer can also grow vertically, and so the footer has the first priority and div.row.content must shrink to give space for the footer if the footer were to grow (as all of this is very dynamic) fetching different data from my DB.

I've tried using flexbox with the 'flex-direction: column', property (vertical), and with different properties.

To clarify, I want the footer to always be shown and growable, and the content to be shrinkable. As you can see the footer is way too big now though (image), giving more available space for the chart in this case. Also, I want the chart to always show, but to have some kind of min-height.

I've included a simpler version to test with, but has the exact same concept.

Thankfully the highcharts API 'reflow' function are constantly listening to the window.resize function, so whenever the window gets resized, the chart (and my table) gets redrawn. This must still be the case within the final solution.

I have a feeling flexbox might not be what I should use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution by removing the `fixed` attribute on the footer so you can use `flex: 1` for the content

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="row content" id="chart-goes-here"></div>
    <div id="footer" class="row footer">
        <button id="btn">Add Content to footer</button>
        <p>If the footer grows, the content must shrink</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>If the footer grows, the content must shrink</p>
    </div>
</div>

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.row.content {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  flex: 1;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: skyblue;
  bottom: 0;
  /*position: fixed;*/ /* <-- get rid of this */
}
```

`reflow` should handle the responsiveness when resizing the window but, if your footer content is dynamic (for example, data retrieved from server), you can just call `chart.reflow()` to update the chart dimensions

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xo0ph6Lv/1/

Comment: Thanks a million, that worked perfectly!!! Been working on this for a loooong time.